# preg_replace with curly brackets

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'd like to replace the string `"{{edit(3)}}"` with `"open3close"` using `preg_replace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry if you wasted your time, i found a valid solution.

```
preg_replace("/{{edit\((.*)\)}}/e","'open'.'\\\1'.'close'", $string);
```

> input : {{edit(3)}}
>   output: open3close

Answer (score 5):

Escape `{` and `}` to `\{` and `\}` in regex string

Comment: i guess it, but something is going wrong, may you suggest me an example?

Comment: @TrustWeb, for example, `preg_replace('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/',"open3close",$text);`